# Using if Condtion in jmeter to validate Dynamic value

Tags: performance, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

I want to validate dynamic value from the response. based on the dynamic value response it will select different popups. How to use if condition to validate dynamic value and navigate the pages as per the dynamic value and use else condition if the value is null.

Please help how to write the code for this condition in jmeter?

Jmeter code to validate the dynamic value

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at JMeter's [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-if-controller) or [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller)

- If Controller run its children if the [JMeter Function or Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) you put into the condition evaluates to `true`
- Switch Controller runs one of its children if name or index of the switch expression matches, otherwise it runs the first direct child.